# Put QpushButton into drop down menu if window/toolbar size/width is reduced

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, pyside2, qtoolbar

I have a QToolBar full of QPushButtons. As the window is resized to reduce its width, the width of toolbar is reduced. If the width is reduced beyond a certain point, the buttons starts disappearing. I think the situations is understood.

There are certain situations when someone has to reduce the window width so setting minimum width is out of the question.

So basically, all those buttons should be accessible regardless of the window size.

I was thinking of putting those buttons into a drop down menu as the widow size is being reduced. (Is there another way?) I don't even know where to start with this. If somebody could tell me how to do this or point me in the right direction, that'd be great.

```
import sys

from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2 import *

class MainWindow(QWidget):
   def __init__(self):
       super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
       self.resize(500, 400)
       self.setMinimumSize(200, 200)

       toolbar = QToolBar()
       toolbar.setStyleSheet("QToolBar{"
                          "background: rgb(60, 60, 60);}")
       toolbar.setFixedHeight(30)

      a = QPushButton()
      a.setFixedSize(25, 25)
      a.setText("a")
      a.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{"
                    "color: red;"
                    "background: yellow;}")
      b = QPushButton()
      b.setFixedSize(25, 25)
      b.setText("b")
      b.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{"
                    "color: red;"
                    "background: yellow;}")
      c = QPushButton()
      c.setFixedSize(25, 25)
      c.setText("c")
      c.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{"
                    "color: red;"
                    "background: yellow;}")
      d = QPushButton()
      d.setFixedSize(25, 25)
      d.setText("d")
      d.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{"
                    "color: red;"
                    "background: yellow;}")
      e = QPushButton()
      e.setFixedSize(25, 25)
      e.setText("e")
      e.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{"
                    "color: red;"
                    "background: yellow;}")
      f = QPushButton()
      f.setFixedSize(25, 25)
      f.setText("f")
      f.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{"
                    "color: red;"
                    "background: yellow;}")
      g = QPushButton()
      g.setFixedSize(25, 25)
      g.setText("g")
      g.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{"
                    "color: red;"
                    "background: yellow;}")
      h = QPushButton()
      h.setFixedSize(25, 25)
      h.setText("h")
      h.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{"
                    "color: red;"
                    "background: yellow;}")
      i = QPushButton()
      i.setFixedSize(25, 25)
      i.setText("i")
      i.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{"
                    "color: red;"
                    "background: yellow;}")
      j = QPushButton()
      j.setFixedSize(25, 25)
      j.setText("j")
      j.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{"
                    "color: red;"
                    "background: yellow}")
      k = QPushButton()
      k.setFixedSize(25, 25)
      k.setText("k")
      k.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{"
                    "color: red;"
                    "background: yellow;}")

      l = QPushButton()
      l.setFixedSize(25, 25)
      l.setText("l")
      l.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{"
                    "color: red;"
                    "background: yellow;}")

      m = QPushButton()
      m.setFixedSize(25, 25)
      m.setText("m")
      m.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{"
                    "color: red;"
                    "background: yellow;}")

      n = QPushButton()
      n.setFixedSize(25, 25)
      n.setText("n")
      n.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{"
                    "color: red;"
                    "background: yellow;}")

      o = QPushButton()
      o.setFixedSize(25, 25)
      o.setText("o")
      o.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{"
                    "color: red;"
                    "background: yellow;}")

      toolbar.addWidget(a)
      toolbar.addWidget(b)
      toolbar.addWidget(c)
      toolbar.addWidget(d)
      toolbar.addWidget(e)
      toolbar.addWidget(f)
      toolbar.addWidget(g)
      toolbar.addWidget(h)
      toolbar.addWidget(i)
      toolbar.addWidget(j)
      toolbar.addWidget(k)
      toolbar.addWidget(l)
      toolbar.addWidget(m)
      toolbar.addWidget(n)
      toolbar.addWidget(o)

      #solution

      toolbar.addAction("m", "m")
      toolbar.addAction("w", "w")
      toolbar.addAction("q", "q")
      toolbar.setStyleSheet("QToolBar{background: grey;}"
                          "QToolButton { background:yellow ;"
                          "color: red;}")          


      layout = QVBoxLayout()
      layout.addWidget(toolbar)
      self.setLayout(layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = MainWindow()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Depending on the chosen style a `QToolBar` *should* provide some means of accessing buttons that are rendered invisible due to the tool bar resizing.

Comment: @eyllanesc I've added some code...

Comment: From Qt docs: "When a toolbar is resized in such a way that it is too small to show all the items it contains, an extension button will appear as the last item in the toolbar. Pressing the extension button will pop up a menu containing the items that do not currently fit in the toolbar." This might only work with actions and not with widgets. I strongly suggest to use actions instead of adding buttons as widgets. Note that you can apply the stylesheet to your toolbar instead (replace QPushButton with QToolButton which is what represents each action).

Comment: That was a good pointer to the solution. Thanks @ypnos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using QPushButtons, I've added the following actions to the QToolBar:

```
toolbar.addAction("m", "m")
toolbar.addAction("w", "w")
toolbar.addAction("q", "q")
toolbar.setStyleSheet("QToolBar{background:grey;}"
                          "QToolButton {background:yellow ;"
                          "color: red;}")
```